# Pandas replace value in multiindex row

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

So, I have a MultiIndex DataFrame and I cannot figure out row to modify a row index value.

In this example, I would like to set c = 1 where the "a" index is 4:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({('colA', 'x1'): {(1, np.nan, 0): np.nan, (4, np.nan, 0): np.nan},
('colA', 'x2'): {(1, np.nan, 0): np.nan, (4, np.nan, 0): np.nan},
('colA', 'x3'): {(1, np.nan, 0): np.nan, (4, np.nan, 0): np.nan},
('colA', 'x4'): {(1, np.nan, 0): np.nan, (4, np.nan, 0): np.nan}})

df.index.set_names(['a', 'b', 'c'], inplace=True)

print(df)


            colA
              x1    x2  x3  x4
a   b   c               
1   NaN 0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN 0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Desired output:

```
            colA
              x1    x2  x3  x4
a   b   c               
1   NaN 0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN 1   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `pandas[df.index['a'] == 4] = 1` ? maybe/

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "pandas"

Comment: oops pandas should be `df[df.index['a'] == 4] = 1`\

Comment: This will give `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: ahh your right. ... give me a minute

Comment: hmmm sorry its a bit harder than i expected... I dont have time to solve it right now ... but here is how you can get the mask to use `mask = df.index.get_level_values('a') == 4`

Comment: it's ok, thank you for the direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Separate the index, process it and put it back together with the data.

### Logic

1. Separate index and process it as a dataframe
2. Prepare a MultiIndex
3. Either of the following two options:

   - combine data and MultiIndex together **`Method-1`**
   - update the index of the original dataframe **`Method-2`**

### Code

```py
# separate the index and process it
names = ['a', 'b', 'c'] # same as df.index.names
#dfd = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())
dfd = df.index.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
dfd.loc[dfd['a']==4, ['c']] = 1

# prepare index for original dataframe: df
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(x) for x in dfd.loc[:, names].values], names=names)

## Method-1
# create new datframe with updated index
dfn = pd.DataFrame(df.values, index=index, columns=df.columns)
# dfn --> new dataframe

## Method-2
# reset the index of original dataframe df
df.set_index(index)
```

**Output**:

```sh
            colA            
              x1  x2  x3  x4
a   b   c                   
1.0 NaN 0.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN
4.0 NaN 1.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

### Dummy Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({('colA', 'x1'): {(1, np.nan, 0): np.nan, (4, np.nan, 0): np.nan},
('colA', 'x2'): {(1, np.nan, 0): np.nan, (4, np.nan, 0): np.nan},
('colA', 'x3'): {(1, np.nan, 0): np.nan, (4, np.nan, 0): np.nan},
('colA', 'x4'): {(1, np.nan, 0): np.nan, (4, np.nan, 0): np.nan}})

df.index.set_names(['a', 'b', 'c'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: @peter_b Here's another option.

Comment: I can see this certainly works but it really feels like an overkill!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we start with `df`.

```
x = df.reset_index()
x.loc[x[x.a == 4].index, 'c'] = 1
x = x.set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(x)

        colA            
          x1  x2  x3  x4
a b   c                 
1 NaN 0  NaN NaN NaN NaN
4 NaN 1  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's no way to do it directly, without reseting the index, right? BC I'm working with a big dataframe in reality

Comment: resetting the index doesn't change the order of the data and the size of the data doesn't really matter.

Comment: big is pretty fluid.. how do you define big?